# Wicket Framework File Structure

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, wicket

normally in wicket you put html and java in the same package. In my application, when I create a html file in my java package, eclipse puts it in the webapp folder. Should I change this somehow or should I try to put somehow a reference to that file in the webapp folder? Otherwise it wouldnt work with the wicket IDs.

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new HTML file through the File menu, right-click the folder/package you want it to be created in and select the `New...` menu there.